# Compatibility of Bioinformatics modules: Should I downgrade for the unsupported modules?

Tags: database, 10, version-control, upgrading

As part of college course work, I am required to make a genomic database for a local website with basic features (like gene search, sequence alignment). I have installed Drupal 10.2.3 with PostgreSQL 14.11, PHP 8.3.4 and Tripal 4.0.0-alpha2.

Problem arises when I try to install essential modules like Tripal BLAST UI and Jbrowse. These are some of the main features I have to implement, but both documentations only show Drupal 7.x compatibility.

My main doubt is, considering the time frame I have to finish this course (1 month), can I afford to wait for module upgradation to support Drupal 10 (Tripal 4), or should I redo the whole project with Drupal 7? Or is there anything else I am missing? I am looking to create this as part of my course project that can be converted to a full-fledged website beyond that (so cannot redo the whole thing after Drupal 7 end-of-support in just a few months).

Note: I am new to Drupal and website development in general. Would appreciate clear instructions or redirection if I am in the wrong forum.